# Generating Linear Extensions of a Partial Order

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, combinatorics

Given a set $S$ and a partial order $\prec$ over $S$, I'm looking for a way to "efficiently" generate a list of linear extensions of $\prec$.  Suppose the partial order is given by a `List` of pairs $\{x,y\}$ such that $x,y\in S$.  For example, if $S = \{a,b,c\}$, then $\{\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}$ defines a partial order where $a \prec c$ and $b \prec c$.

Essentially, given a list $S$ and a list of pairs $P$, I want to generate a list of permutations which respect the orders of the pairs in $P$.

```
linearExtensions[{a, b, c, d, e}, {{a, b}, {c, b}, {c, d}, {e, d}}]
(* {{a, c, b, e, d}, {a, c, e, b, d}, {a, c, e, d, b}, {a, e, c, b, d},
    {a, e, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, e, d}, {c, a, e, b, d}, {c, a, e, d, b},
    {c, e, a, b, d}, {c, e, a, d, b}, {c, e, d, a, b}, {e, a, c, b, d},
    {e, a, c, d, b}, {e, c, a, b, d}, {e, c, a, d, b}, {e, c, d, a, b}} *)
```

Since $\{a,b\}$ is in $P$, the permutation $\{b, c, a, d, e\}$ is not a linear extension because $b$ comes before $a$.

I've written two different functions which do the job, both using pattern matching, but I've been using Mathematica for less than a week and am still getting into the functional mindset.  I'm interested to see how seasoned Mathematica users would tackle this problem.

My first approach was to use `NestWhile` (edit: this is ugly! I did not know about the `Fold[]` function when I wrote this):

```
linearExtensions[set_, po_] := 
    Module[{patterns},
        patterns = {___, #[[1]], ___, #[[2]], ___}& /@ po;
        First@NestWhile[{Cases[#[[1]], First[#[[2]]]], Rest[#[[2]]]}&,
            {Permutations[set], patterns}, Length[#[[2]]] > 0&]
    ]
```

My second approach, which turned out to be significantly slower, was to expand a set of rules from the partial order and use `Select` on the list of permutations.

```
linearExtensions[set_, po_] :=
    Module[{poQ},
        poQ[rule_] := And @@ (MatchQ[rule, {___, #[[1]], ___, #[[2]], ___}]& /@ po);
        Select[Permutations[set], poQ[#]&]
    ]
```

Note that on a list of length $n$ there can be $\Omega(n!)$ linear extensions, so by "efficient," I don't mean polynomial-time.

Comment: What's $\Omega$?

Comment: @alancalvitti The counter part to [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). $\Omega$ is an asymptotic lower bound

Comment: @R.M, same as small $o$?

Comment: @alancalvitti $\Omega$ is an asymptotic lower bound.  Think of $O$ as $\le$, $o$ as $<$, and $\Omega$ as $\ge$.  (The analogy falls apart for some pairs of functions which are neither $O$ nor $\Omega$ of each other.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could use integer linear programming. In Mathematica this can be done with Reduce[]. One way (probably not the best) to set this up is shown below. It uses an array of 0-1 variables, where a 1 in position (j,k) will indicate that the kth element of the input variables goes in position j of a particular ordering.

Caveat: I may have mixed up rows and columns.

```
consistentOrders[elems_, pairorders_] := Module[
  {n = Length[elems], vars, x, fvars, c1, c2, c3, c4, constraints, 
   ineqs, solns},
  ineqs[{a1_, a2_}, n_, v_] := 
   Table[Total[Take[v[[All, a1]], j]] >= 
     Total[Take[v[[All, a2]], j]], {j, 1, n - 1}];
  vars = Array[x, {n, n}];
  fvars = Flatten[vars];
  c1 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
  c2 = Thread[Total[vars] == 1];
  c3 = Thread[Total[Transpose@vars] == 1];
  c4 = Flatten[
    Map[ineqs[#, n, vars] &, pairorders /. Thread[elems -> Range[n]]]];
  constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3, c4];
  solns = Reduce[constraints, fvars, Integers];
  solns = 
   solns /. {(_ == 0) :> Sequence[], aa_ == 1 :> aa, And -> List, 
     Or -> List};
  Sort[solns /. x[i_, j_] :> elems[[j]]]
  ]
```

--- edit ---

The first three constraint sets are fairly standard for this type of 0-1 programming. The fourth constraint subset arises as follows. The idea is that if the jth list element must precede the kth, then the 1 in column j must occur in an earlier row than the one in column k. So for every 1<=m<=n-1 (n=dimension) the sum of the first m entries in col j >= corresponding sum in col k.

--- end edit ---
Example:

```
consistentOrders[{a, b, c, d, 
  e}, {{a, b}, {c, b}, {c, d}, {e, d}}]

(* Out[83]= {{a, c, b, e, d}, {a, c, e, b, d}, {a, c, e, d, b}, {a, e, c,
   b, d}, {a, e, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, e, d}, {c, a, e, b, d}, {c, a, e,
   d, b}, {c, e, a, b, d}, {c, e, a, d, b}, {c, e, d, a, b}, {e, a, c,
   b, d}, {e, a, c, d, b}, {e, c, a, b, d}, {e, c, a, d, b}, {e, c, d,
   a, b}} *)
```

Bigger example:

```
vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l};
porderlist = {{a, c}, {b, c}, {f, g}, {g, e}, {d, a}, {h, i}, {i, 
    d}, {g, h}, {g, i}, {h, j}, {h, k}, {k, j}, {k, c}};

Timing[ss = consistentOrders[vars, porderlist];]

(* Out[81]= {60.03, Null}

In[82]:= Length[ss]

Out[82]= 12840 *)
```

Comment: Can you explain the fourth constraint?

Comment: Not easily... See edited response.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Nice! I didn't think to use integer programming for this.  This is certainly the most efficient solution so far.

Comment: Although it's not as concise, I'm accepting this answer because its performance trumps the others'.

Comment: The code is incorrect:

consistentOrders[{a, b, c, d}, {{a, b}, {b, d}, {c, d}}] needs to generate the linear extensions of a 4-element tree. It has maximum element d in its Hasse diagram.

The result (of the above code):

{{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {c, a, b, d}}

produces three linear extensions (as expected).

{c, a, b, d} is not consistent with the given order. The answer needs to be {b, c, a, d} for permutations in row notation.

{c, a, b, d} means for a permutation in row notation:

a is assigned c, b is assigned a, c is assigned b, d is assigned d

Comment: @Mike I fail to see how the order `c<a<b<d` violates any of `(a<b,b<d,c<d)`.

Comment: I assumed that since {c, a, b, d} were referred to as permutations, this meant assigning the values c to a, a to b, b to c and d to d to generate the linear extension of the order (where a < b < c < d in the associated total order). I did not interpret them as a linear order  c < a < b < d.  Thanks for clarifying. In that case there is no error.

Answer (score 6):

A more concise version of the first approach, using `Fold[]` instead of `NestWhile[]`:

```
linearExtensions[set_, po_] :=
    Fold[Cases, Permutations[set], {___, #1, ___, #2, ___} & @@@ po]
```

Comment: Or, `linearExtensions[set_, po_] := Fold[Cases[#1, Riffle[#2, ___, {1, -1, 2}]] &, Permutations[set], po]`

Answer (score 4):

My first modest attempt:

```
linearExtensions[set_List, po_?MatrixQ] :=
    Select[Permutations[set], Complement[po, Subsets[#, {Last[Dimensions[po]]}]] === {} &]
```

My second modest attempt:

```
linearExtensions[set_List, po_?MatrixQ] :=
  Select[Permutations[set], And @@ Map[Function[p, LongestCommonSequence[#, p] === p], po] &]
```

Comment: Nice!  I didn't realize Subsets preserved order.  Is there no nicer way to determine if a list is a subset of another than what you're doing here?

Comment: If there is one, I do not know it.

Comment: Interestingly, the pattern matching seems to be much faster than this.  Try, for example, with `linearExtensions[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 
  i}, {{a, c}, {b, c}, {f, g}, {g, e}, {d, a}, {h, i}, {i, d}, {g, h}}]`.

Comment: @Zach, yes; it seems your approach is a good bit faster... anyway, I gave another possibility.

Answer (score 4):

I like @Daniel's approach using 0/1 integer programming. Instead of Reduce, however, one can achieve more optimal performance using SatisfiabilityInstances. In the code below, I've written the main function (AllTotalOrderings) for determining all total orderings of a partially ordered *graph*. It is then easy to encode the desired linearExtensions function as a simple call to AllTotalOrderings, for a suitably constructed graph. 
To further increase performance I've made use of CanonicalGraph (so as to introduce the constraints to the SAT solver in the most efficient order) and TransitiveReductionGraph (to minimize the number of constraints given to the SAT solver.) Note that I'm using the [undocumented Method->"BDD"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103736/58438) to call SatisfiabilityInstances, and BooleanConvert to preprocess the constraints into a [natively-optimized Boolean Decision Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59052#comment270807_59052). The ordering is extracted from the output of the SAT solver using ArrayReshape and the [AdjacencyLists property of SparseArray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/58438).

```
AllTotalOrderings[g_Graph]:=With[{canonicalgraph=CanonicalGraph[g],v=VertexCount[g]},
With[{orderedvlist=Values[KeySort[First[FindGraphIsomorphism[canonicalgraph,g]]]]},
Map[orderedvlist[[Flatten[ArrayReshape[SparseArray[Boole[#]],{v,v}]["AdjacencyLists"]]]]&,
Block[{Pos},SatisfiabilityInstances[
BooleanConvert[And[
And@@Table[BooleanCountingFunction[{1},v]@@Table[Indexed[Pos,{i,j}],j,v}],{i,v}],
And@@Table[BooleanCountingFunction[{1},v]@@Table[Indexed[Pos,{j,i}],{j,v}],{i,v}],
And@@Function[{i,j},And@@Table[And[Implies[
Indexed[Pos,{r,i}],Nor@@Table[Indexed[Pos,{k,j}],{k,1,r}]]],{r,1,v}]
]@@@EdgeList[TransitiveReductionGraph[canonicalgraph]]],"BFF"]//Head,
All,Method->"BDD"]]]]];
```

and

```
linearExtensions[set_List, po_?MatrixQ]:=AllTotalOrderings[Graph[set,DirectedEdge@@@po]];
```

This give dramatically improved performance. For the example in question,

```
With[{vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l},
porderlist = {{a, c}, {b, c}, {f, g}, {g, e}, {d, a}, {h, i}, {i, d}, {g, h}, {g, i}, {h, j}, {h, k}, {k, j}, {k, c}}},
Timing[Length[linearExtensions[vars, porderlist]]]]

(*Out[] = {1.53125, 12840}*)
```

Comment: Very nice first post! Welcome to MSE.

Comment: This is great! But do be aware TransitiveReductionGraph is known to have [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/17).