# Binary decision diagrams (BDD) syntax error

Tags: syntax, warning-messages, binary

I am new here (and to *Mathematica*) and would like to rebuild a simple binary decision diagram that I found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

A code has been provided as part of an answer to a related question ([Binary decision diagrams (BDD)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59052/binary-decision-diagrams-bdd)), but it seems to generate a syntax error when running it in *Mathematica*.
Please see the code and error message below. Could anyone tell me what I have to do to fix it? Apologies in case this is a very simple question...

```
bf = BooleanConvert @ BooleanFunction[12432, 4][a, b, c, d]
```

> ```
> (a && b && ! c) || (! a && b && c && d) || (b && ! c && ! d)
> ```

We can convert this to if-and-constants form:

```
BooleanConvert[bf, "IF"]
```

> ```
> If[a, 
>     If[b, If[c, False, True], False], 
>     If[b, If[c, If[d, True, False], If[d, False, True]], False]]
> ```

Here's a function that converts a boolean function to its if-and-constants form, and visualizes it as a graph:

```
ClearAll[bddGraph];
bddGraph[bf_] :=
  With[{eq = Replace[BooleanConvert[bf, "IF"], If -> List, ∞, Heads -> True]},
  Graph[
    (Labeled[#, Extract[eq, # ~ Append ~ 1]] & /@ Position[eq, _List]) 
    ~ Join ~
    (Labeled[#, #] & /@ {True, False}),
    Flatten[
      {Labeled[# \[DirectedEdge] # ~ Append ~ 2, True], 
       Labeled[# \[DirectedEdge] # ~ Append ~ 3, False]} & /@
         Position[eq, _List], 2]
     /. 
     a_ \[DirectedEdge] b_ :> 
       a \[DirectedEdge] Extract[eq, b] /; BooleanQ[Extract[eq, b]]]]
```

Now we can visualize the decision tree:

```
bddGraph[bf]
```

[image: bdd]

However, instead of seeing the graph, I got the following error message:

> Syntax::sntxf: "!(*StyleBox[\"\\"\\\\"\\"\",
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[!(#),
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[\"\\"\\\\" cannot be followed by
>   \\\\"\\"\", \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[!(((\[ DirectedEdge]))
>   ((# ~ Append ~ 2))),
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[\"\\"\\\\".\\"\",
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[!(\"\"), \"MT\"])"
>
> Syntax::tsntxi: "!(*StyleBox[\"\\"\\\\"\\"\",
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[!(\[ DirectedEdge]),
>   \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[\"\\"\\\\" is incomplete; more input is
>   needed.\\"\", \"MT\"])!(*StyleBox[!(\"\"), \"MT\"])"
>
> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.

Comment: Could you provide the input values you use? I ran the code you've provided with arguments in a format of : `{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 
    1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}` and it produced no error.

Comment: I believe there is an issue in the way your Mathematica IDE has interpreted the code you've copy/pasted. Could you please provide the version of Mathematica, I believe this could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I am using Mathematica 7.0

Comment: And yes, the input values I wanted to use were the same as in your case!

Comment: `bddGraph[BooleanConvert@BooleanFunction[12432, 4][a, b, c, d]]` works perfectly on my system: V10.2 running on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: BTW, If you are not seeing the graph, how did generate the image of it that included in question?

Comment: Thanks again- I think I should simply try to upgrade my Mathematica version in that case. The tree above is simple copied and pasted from a related thread using the same example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running V10.3 on OS X 10.10.2, I can find nothing wrong with the OP code. I do not get the error messages he reports.

However, I found this an interesting problem and worked my own way of producing a binary decision diagram. I did it in my usual pedestrian way and produce code much more prolix than brilliantly concise but rather opaque code posted in the question. I present my work here because it provides a second, completely independent solution, and I believe it has some virtues, the principal one being that my code is much easier to understand.

#### Example data

```
vars = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
expr = BooleanConvert[BooleanFunction[12432, 4] @@ vars, "IF"];
```

Note that I am using strings to identify the nodes. The reason for this will become clear if you read my code. Whether this is a good hack or not is open to debate.

#### Functions

There a fair number of them. This is a divide-and-conquer approach.

`indexExpr` indexes the node identifiers to make them (temporarily) unique. It also builds `vMap`, an association that contains rules of the form *`<vertex-name> -> <vertex-index>`*.

```
indexExpr[expr_If] :=
  Module[{k = 0, indexed, vMap = Association[]},
    indexed =
      Activate[
        Inactivate[expr, If] /. 
          s_String :> (ss = s <> ToString[++k]; AssociateTo[vMap, ss -> k]; ss)];
    vMap = Join[vMap, Association[{True -> ++k, False -> ++k}]];
    {indexed, vMap}]
```

Before the graph can be drawn, the indices post-fixed onto the vertex labels must be removed, which is `deindexVars` job.

```
deindexVars[Rule[k_, v_String]] := Rule[k, StringReplace[v, DigitCharacter .. -> ""]]
deindexVars[x_] := x
```

`makeGraph` makes a recursive traversal of the nested If-forms to produce the arguments wanted by `Graph`. The labels for the terminal `True` and `False` nodes are tacked on after the recursion completes.

```
makeGraph[expr_If] :=
  Block[{indexedExpr, vMap, edges = {}, elbls = {}, vlbls = {}},
    {indexedExpr, vMap} = indexExpr[expr];
    helper[vMap, indexedExpr];
    vlbls =
      Join[
        deindexVars /@ vlbls,
        {vMap[True] -> Placed[True, Below], vMap[False] -> Placed[False, Below]}];
    Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> elbls, VertexLabels -> vlbls]]
```

This handles the case where both the *then* branch and the *else* branch of an If-form are terminal.

```
helper[vertexMap_, If[s_, lf : (True | False), rt : True | False]] :=
  Module[{lfEdge, rtEdge},
    {lfEdge, rtEdge} = 
      {DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[lf]], 
       DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[rt]]};
    edgeHelper[lfEdge, rtEdge];
    AppendTo[vlbls, vertexMap[s] -> s];]
```

This handles the case where the *then* branch of an If-form continues and the *else* branch is terminal.

```
helper[vertexMap_, If[s_, lf : If_, rt : True | False]] :=
  Module[{lfEdge, rtEdge},
    {lfEdge, rtEdge} = 
      {DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[lf[[1]]]], 
       DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[rt]]};
     edgeHelper[lfEdge, rtEdge];
     AppendTo[vlbls, vertexMap[s] -> s];
     helper[vertexMap, lf];]
```

This handles the case where the *then* branch of the an If-form is terminal and the *else* branch continues.

```
helper[vertexMap_, If[s_, lf : True | False, rt_If]] :=
  Module[{lfEdge, rtEdge},
    {lfEdge, rtEdge} = 
      {DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[lf]], 
       DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[rt[[1]]]]};
    edgeHelper[lfEdge, rtEdge];
    AppendTo[vlbls, vertexMap[s] -> s];
    helper[vertexMap, rt];]
```

This handles the case where both the *then* branch and the *else* branch of an If-form continues.

```
helper[vertexMap_, If[s_, lf_If, rt_If]] :=
  Module[{lfEdge, rtEdge},
    {lfEdge, rtEdge} = 
      {DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[lf[[1]]]], 
       DirectedEdge[vertexMap[s], vertexMap[rt[[1]]]]};
    edgeHelper[lfEdge, rtEdge];
    AppendTo[vlbls, vertexMap[s] -> s];
    helper[vertexMap, lf];
    helper[vertexMap, rt];]
```

That takes care of the recursion. There is one more function that carries out a simple common task for the `helper` variants.

```
edgeHelper[lf_, rt_] :=
  (edges = Join[edges, {lf, rt}];
   elbls =
     Join[
       elbls,
       {lf -> Style[True, Background -> White], 
        rt -> Style[False, Background -> White]}];)
```

#### Example

```
makeGraph[expr]
```

[image: graph]