# How to inspect the learned ClassifierFunction decision tree model?

Tags: export, machine-learning

Assume I have a `ClassifierFunction` object learned like this:

```
classifier = Classify[trainSet, Method -> "DecisionTree"]
```

Then how can I extract the actual decision tree structure from the result?

Here an example:

```
fn[n_] := Which[n < 1, 1, 1 <= n < 2, 2, 2 <= n, 3];
data = Table[(r = RandomReal[{0, 4}]; r -> fn[r]), {i, 1, 1000}];
c = Classify[data, Method -> "DecisionTree"];
```

Comment: Hard to answer without a concrete minimal example for `trainSet`.

Comment: How about this step function with a branching in decision? `fn[n_] := Which[n < 1, 1, 1 <= n < 2, 2, 2 <= n, 3];`. Data generated as 
`data = Table[(r = RandomReal[{0, 4}]; r -> fn[r, 1, 2, 3]), {i, 1, 
    1000}];`  and classifying using `c = Classify[data, Method -> "DecisionTree"];`  then trying to visuallize using `c[[1, "Model", "Tree"]]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - I see an output like this `See an output like this for the question `<|FeatureIndices->RawArray[Integer16,<2>],NumericalThresholds->RawArray[Real32,<2>],NominalSplits->{},Children->RawArray[Integer16,<2,2>],LeafValues->RawArray[UnsignedInteger16,<3,3>],RootIndex->2,NominalDimension->0|>` with `classifier[[1, "Model", "Tree"]]` . Can be improved further?

Comment: Are you interested in visualizing the Decision Trees made by Classify, or you just want to visualize a Decision Tree over some data?

Comment: @AntonAntonov - I was curious about visualizing the DecisionTrees made by Classify... Your answer in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181763/716) was what I was looking for

Comment: @myaccount_ram You can take a look at [this MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95139/34008) of ["Creating Identification/Classification trees"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75801/34008). And [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99351/34008) is another Decision Trees visualization application.

Comment: @AntonAntonov is it possible to visualize the output of Classify[]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to visualize/interpret `Classify`'s tree structure from [Henrik Schumacher's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180721/34008).

```
SeedRandom[432]
fn[n_] := Which[n < 1, 1, 1 <= n < 2, 2, 2 <= n, 3];
data = Table[(r = RandomReal[{0, 4}]; r -> fn[r]), {i, 1, 1000}];
c = Classify[data, Method -> "DecisionTree"];

tree = c[[1, "Model", "Tree"]];

fromRawArray[a_RawArray] := Developer`FromRawArray[a];
fromRawArray[a_] := a;
Map[Normal, fromRawArray /@ tree[[1]]]

(* <|"FeatureIndices" -> {1, 1}, 
 "NumericalThresholds" -> {-0.894867, -0.0252423}, 
 "NominalSplits" -> {}, "Children" -> {{-2, -3}, {1, -1}}, 
 "LeafValues" -> {{1, 1, 508}, {246, 1, 1}, {1, 249, 1}}, 
 "RootIndex" -> 2, "NominalDimension" -> 0|> *)

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/AVCDecisionTreeForest.m"]

dtree = BuildDecisionTree[List @@@ data]

(* {{0.374931, 1.9972, 1, Number, 
  1000}, {{0.499981, 1.0175, 1, Number, 
   493}, {{{245, 1}}}, {{{248, 2}}}}, {{{507, 3}}}} *)

LayeredGraphPlot[DecisionTreeToRules[dtree], 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

There is a discrepancy of 1 in the obtained values, but otherwise the second tree seems to approximate `Classify`'s one well. The splitting thresholds of `Classify`'s tree a most likely obtained over the data being transformed with some embedding/hashing/normalization.

Comment: Note: this visualization is NOT that of Classify[], but that of BuildDecisionTree[]

Comment: @myaccount_ram I thought this is clear from my explanations, but I guess it isn't...

Answer (score 5):

In general, many objects generated by Mathematica can be inspected by trying things of the form `InputForm[classifier]` or `classifier[string]` with string being one of the elements of `classifier["Properties"]`. Recently implemented objects such as ClassifierFunction are mere wrappers for well-structured `Association`s (thumbs up for this approach!), so `classifier[[1]]` can be very revealing.

The following reveals that

```
tree = c[[1, "Model", "Tree"]]
```

is another such object (with head `` MachineLearning`DecisionTree ``).

Inspecting

```
tree[[1]]
```

reveals that `` MachineLearning`DecisionTree `` are partially composed of `RawArray`s. These can be converted to usual integer arrays as follows:

```
fromRawArray[a_RawArray] := Developer`FromRawArray[a];
fromRawArray[a_] := a;
fromRawArray /@ tree[[1]]
```

> <|"FeatureIndices" -> {1, 1}, 
>    "NumericalThresholds" -> {0.402823, 0.82983}, "NominalSplits" -> {}, 
>    "Children" -> {{-1, 2}, {-2, -3}}, 
>    "LeafValues" -> {{619, 1, 1}, {1, 130, 1}, {1, 1, 254}}, 
>    "RootIndex" -> 1, "NominalDimension" -> 0|>

But I cannot tell you how to interpret this data. I would have to learn first what a decision tree is and how it is constructed...