# Why is SatisfiabilityCount faster than SatisfiableQ?

Tags: performance-tuning, undocumented, boolean-computation

Consider the following (large) Boolean expression, which arose in a SAT problem. (The expression is not satisfiable.)

```
bigExpr = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/gEgGQ26S"];
```

On my system (*Mathematica* 10.3 on Windows 10), I observed the following strange behavior: `SatisfiableQ[bigExpr, BooleanVariables@bigExpr]` takes 4.53883 seconds to run, while `SatisfiabilityCount[bigExpr, BooleanVariables@bigExpr]` takes only 0.00588 seconds.

How can it be the case that `SatisfiableQ`, which only checks for the existence of a satisfying assignment, takes three orders of magnitude more time than `SatisfiabilityCount`, which *counts* them?

Comment: I'd venture `SatisfiabilityCount` is doing a minimization first, e.g., try `SatisfiableQ[BooleanMinimize[bigExpr]]` - times are comparable in a quick test here.

Comment: Just for the record I've had related - unexplained behavior - experience with some of the Mathematica machine learning functions. Mathematica Support pointed me at some undocumented arguments that enabled me to make sense out of behavior on some "edge" inputs. In summary, Support was very helpful, documentation not so much.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

SatisfiableQ has three methods:

- "BDD": converts the expression to a BDD (binary decision diagram),
- "SAT": uses the Minisat library,
- "TREE": a branch-and-bound method based on the expression tree.

`SatisfiabilityCount` counts instances by converting the expression to a BDD, so its timing should be close to `SatisfiableQ` with the "BDD" method (counting instances once we have a BDD is fast).

Unfortunately, for this example the automatic method choice heuristic picks the worst method.

```
Timing[SatisfiableQ[bigExpr, BooleanVariables[bigExpr], Method->#]]& 
  /@ {Automatic, "BDD", "SAT", "TREE"}
```

> `{{3.41648, False}, {0.021996, False}, {0.004, False}, {3.47947, False}}`

Comment: Ah, I had no idea `SatisfiableQ` had a `Method` option. This should really be documented.

Comment: Actually, how do you know that `Method -> "SAT"` calls the MiniSAT library? I can't find any reference to this fact.

Comment: @DavidZhang http://members.wolfram.com/adams/