# Mathematica vs. state-of-the-art SAT solvers

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I found some fascinating paper by Marijn Heule and Oliver Kullmann on advances in [SAT solvers and automated reasoning](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2017/8/219606-the-science-of-brute-force/fulltext). In particular, the authors where able to show (a year earlier) a [breakthrough result on a decade old problem through automated reasoning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00723), showing that state of the art tools on solving boolean satifyability problem are very powerful these days.

I am curious how Mathematica's SAT solver compares to these developments. Does Mathematica's function [SatisfiableQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiableQ.html) or [SatisfiabilityInstances](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityCount.html) use clever techniques such as [Conflict-Driven Clause Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-driven_clause_learning), [look-ahead](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/marijn/publications/p01c05_lah.pdf) or Cube-And-Conquere?

The background of my question is the following: I am able to map certain hard problems to boolean formulars, and wonder whether it is immediatly worth learning these other techniques, or is Mathematica sufficently clever solving these systems (or is it basically trying with pure brute-force to find solutions?)

---

One useful [previous answer by a Wolfram developer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103736/12750) can be found here, which sets the stage for my question (which methods have been used 3 years ago, but not what explicit techniques and how they compare to state-of-the-art)

Comment: I am not very familiar with SAT solvers, but I did experiment with other solvers (such as glucose) when developing the graph colouring functionality of IGraph/M. Using them did not give a consistent or significant speedup compared to using Mathematica's.

Comment: But it should be easy to put problems into a conjunctive normal form, export them, and ty other SAT solvers.

Comment: Mathematica claims "industrial strength" Boolean computation so its SATSolver should be doing better than "brute force". On the other hand, SATSolvers tend to specialise on formulae type (satisfiable, unsatisfiable, random, etc) or available resources (time, space, parallelization) or especially, exploiting a domain's structure, so it might be optimistic to hope for leading-edge performance across the board (curiously, in Heule, Kullman and Marek’s breakthrough paper mentioned in the OP’s introduction, after colouring the natural numbers red and blue ...

Comment: ... the SAT (CNF) instances that encode the unavoidablity of monochromatic pythagorean triples are reminiscent of *random* CNF formulae). To compare *Mathematica*’s SATSolver you could use the benchmarks provided in the [2018 SAT Competition](http://sat2018.forsyte.tuwien.ac.at/index.php?cat=results) where, given this [competition’s history](http://www.satcompetition.org) Maple’s SATSolver(s) seems to be laying down the gauntlet which might pique WRI’s interest … (Another indicator of state-of-the-art solvers is the ability to generate so-called *DRAT* proof files ...

Comment: ... for use in verifying unsatisfiability  claims but which seems absent as an option in `SatisfiabilityInstances`?). Alternatively, providing some benchmarks in the question would allow comparative answers - a natural starting point might be the paper’s SAT encodings generated by a WL-version of the (19-line C) encodings provided [by the authors](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~marijn/ptn/) in the file *Ptn-encode*.

Comment: SAT Competition did change, at present it is: [SAT Competition](https://satcompetition.github.io/).